# Как сделать инъекцию бина в Spring в зависимости от условия?

Tags: java, spring

Как я могу сделать инъекцию бина в зависимости от условия? У меня есть `@Autowired` бин, который должен быть проинициализирован, когда выбраны Spring-профили **A** и **B**, и не должен инициалазироваться, когда выбран профиль **C**.

**P.S.:** Spring конфигурирую в xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Spring есть аннотация `@Lazy`, которая указывает, что данный бин должен быть проинициализирован "лениво", то есть инициализации не будет, пока не произойдёт первое обращение к бину.

Эта аннотация может быть добавлена как к классу конфигурации *(в этом случае все бины будут загружаться лениво)*, так и к конфигу конкретного бина, компоненту или полю, отмеченному аннотацией `@Autowired`.

Answer (score 1):

Я знаю несколько простых способов сделать то что вам требуется:

1. Если вы используете профили для разного конфигурирования приложения можно воспользоваться аннотацией `@Profile("!С")`, если поставить данную аннотацию над бином он будет инициализирован только в том случае если профиль не `C`. (Профиль можно задать в настройках `Intellij idea`). [Ссылка](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-latest-ru/spring_profiles.html) на тему профилей
2. Создать свойство в файле ресурсов `application.yaml` относительно которого потом решать создавать бин или нет c помощью аннотации `@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "anyprefix", name = "bin", havingValue = "true")`.

Ссылки на тему данной аннотации: [вот](https://habr.com/ru/post/462541/) и [вот](https://codingnconcepts.com/spring-boot/conditional-annotations-in-spring-boot/), также есть [похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64228084/conditionalonproperty-for-complex-objects-to-yaml)